# Grails and ActiveMQ: How to manage connections for DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

I'm looking for an alternative to the plugin approach (jms and/or the camel routing plugin) to consuming ActiveMQ from Grails. So far so good, but I'm not able to find any good solutions for managing the connection.

Here's my config/spring/resources.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer

beans = {
    jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
        targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
            brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61616"
        }
    }

    jmsMessageListener(MessageListenerAdapter, ref("myService")) {
        defaultListenerMethod = "onIncomingMessage"
    }

    jmsContainer(DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
        connectionFactory = jmsConnectionFactory
        destinationName = "StatusSavedTopic"
        messageListener = jmsMessageListener
        autoStartup = true

        // Tells the magic sauce to be an ActiveMQ topic
        pubSubDomain = true
    }
}
```

If I set `autoStartup` to true, it works fine with `run-app` until I save my service, causing a recompile. When this happen, the connection is dropped (confirmed by checking the ActiveMQ web console), and no more messages are received (obviously).

Are there ways of ensuring that my `jmsContainer` stays alive, other than not doing this by hand and using the jms or routing plugins?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but the routing plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/routing) documentation notes the following: "Route reloading has been removed. Apache Camel does not support route reloading and the existing hack didn't work properly in the latest version of that library." (I know you are not using the plugin, but perhaps the underlying cause of your issue is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering myself because I found a solution.

The solution is to have an embedded ActiveMQ broker in-process. I always post messages to this embedded broker, and I don't have to test for its availability or handle reconnects, for obvious reasons - it's right there, in my process.

ActiveMQ itself then has a way of connecting brokers so that messages in one are always delivered to the next, and where ActiveMQ handles all the connection stuff automatically. Both the initial connection if the broker is down on app startup, or reconnecting if the broker goes down in flight.

You're free to choose the storage for the embedded broker too. If you persist the messages to disk, ActiveMq will also take care of posting messages to the central broker if your app goes down after a message was queued in the embedded broker but before ActiveMQ managed to deliver to the central broker.

Here's the bean code in grails-app/conf/spring for setting it app up. I'm a bit of a spring noob, so I'm sure there are better ways. Using MethodInvokingFactoryBean made it easy to not do all the fancy initialization with Spring itself, which helped me get this show on the road.

```
activemqLocalMessageDeliveryConnection(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
    targetClass = "com.myapp.ActiveMQLocalBrokerHelper"
    targetMethod = "createConnection"
    arguments = [ref("grailsApplication")]
}

activemqLocalMessageDeliveryProducerSession(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
    targetClass = "com.myapp.ActiveMQLocalBrokerHelper"
    targetMethod = "createProducerSession"
    arguments = [ref("activemqLocalMessageDeliveryConnection")]
}

activemqLocalMessageDeliveryProducer(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) { bean ->
    targetClass = "com.myapp.ActiveMQLocalBrokerHelper"
    targetMethod = "createProducer"
    arguments = [ref("grailsApplication"), ref("activemqLocalMessageDeliveryProducerSession")]
}
```

Here's the code for ActiveMQLocalBrokerHelper.

```
package com.myapp
import java.io.File
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination

class ActiveMQLocalBrokerHelper {
    static javax.jms.Connection createConnection(grailsApplication) {
        // http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html
        def localBrokerName = "localMessageDelivery"

        def broker = new org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService()
        broker.setPersistent(false)
        broker.setBrokerName(localBrokerName)
        broker.start()

        def connFactory = new org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory(broker.getVmConnectorURI());
        def conn = connFactory.createConnection();
        conn.start()

        return conn
    }

    static javax.jms.Session createProducerSession(conn) {
        def session = conn.createSession(true, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return session
    }

    static javax.jms.MessageProducer createProducer(grailsApplication, session) {
        def destination  = session.createQueue("MessageDelivery")
        def producer = session.createProducer(destination)
        producer.setDeliveryMode(javax.jms.DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
        return producer
    }
}
```

That's all you need to get an embedded ActiveMQ broker. This particular one is not persistent, and is transactional. You're free to use the ActiveMQ Java API to do whatever here, of course. To enqueue and consume messages, you just use the normal ActiveMQ APIs. Example:

```
def activemqLocalMessageDeliveryProducer // Inject the producer
def activemqLocalMessageDeliveryProducerSession // And the session

void enqueue(String messageText) {
    def message = session.createTextMessage(messageText)
    producer.send(message)
    session.commit()
}
```

For consuming:

```
def activemqLocalMessageDeliveryConnection // Inject the connection

void consume() {
    def activemqSession = activemqLocalMessageDeliveryConnection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    def destination = activemqSession.createQueue("MyQueueName")
    def consumer = activemqSession.createConsumer(destination)
    while (true) {
        def message = consumer.receive()
        // Do something with message
    }
}
```